# RMAN list archivelogs that are needed for to recover specified backup

Tags: oracle, recovery, rman, backup

I've taken backup of datafiles in 31.12.2013. It completed datafile backups successfully, but archivelog backups failed.

Now, I want to determine what archivelogs should I backup to be sure that my database will be recoverable after restoring 31.12.2013 backup of datafiles.

Comment: It will be some incarnation of RESTORE ... VALIDATE;

Comment: Check the following MOS note:How to determine minimum end point for recovery of an RMAN backup (Doc ID 1329415.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try (requires at least Oracle 10g):

```
RESTORE DATABASE PREVIEW;
```

You'll need at least the archive logs generated during the entire backup operation.

A quick demo:

```
C:\Users>rman target /

Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Jan 8 14:34:28 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: CDB12C (DBID=4034496039)

RMAN> list backup of database summary completed after 'sysdate - 1';

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog

List of Backups
===============
Key     TY LV S Device Type Completion Time    #Pieces #Copies Compressed Tag
------- -- -- - ----------- ------------------ ------- ------- ---------- ---
1       B  F  A DISK        08-jan-14:14:23:45 1       1       NO         TAG20140108T141855
2       B  F  A DISK        08-jan-14:14:24:48 1       1       NO         TAG20140108T141855
3       B  F  A DISK        08-jan-14:14:25:46 1       1       NO         TAG20140108T141855

RMAN> restore database preview summary from tag = TAG20140108T141855;

Starting restore at 08-jan-14:14:34:47
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=30 device type=DISK


List of Backups
===============
Key     TY LV S Device Type Completion Time    #Pieces #Copies Compressed Tag
------- -- -- - ----------- ------------------ ------- ------- ---------- ---
1       B  F  A DISK        08-jan-14:14:23:44 1       1       NO         TAG20140108T141855
3       B  F  A DISK        08-jan-14:14:25:30 1       1       NO         TAG20140108T141855
2       B  F  A DISK        08-jan-14:14:24:31 1       1       NO         TAG20140108T141855
using channel ORA_DISK_1

List of Archived Log Copies for database with db_unique_name CDB12C
=====================================================================

Key     Thrd Seq     S Low Time
------- ---- ------- - ------------------
1       1    13      A 03-jan-14:15:01:14
        Name: C:\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\CDB12C\ARCHIVELOG\2014_01_08\O1_MF_1_13_9DTNSSGR_.ARC

Media recovery start SCN is 2475111
Recovery must be done beyond SCN 2475373 to clear datafile fuzziness
Finished restore at 08-jan-14:14:34:49



RMAN> list archivelog from scn 2475111 until scn 2475374;

List of Archived Log Copies for database with db_unique_name CDB12C
=====================================================================

Key     Thrd Seq     S Low Time
------- ---- ------- - ------------------
1       1    13      A 03-jan-14:15:01:14
        Name: C:\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\CDB12C\ARCHIVELOG\2014_01_08\O1_MF_1_13_9DTNSSGR_.ARC
```

Note the scn min-max indications in the *restore ... preview* output:

> Media recovery start SCN is 2475111 Recovery must be done beyond SCN
>   2475373 to clear datafile fuzziness

So to go beyond the indicated scn, we search for archived logs that contain scn 2475373 + 1.

If you want to verify manually, check the following MOS Note:
*How to determine minimum end point for recovery of an RMAN backup (Doc ID 1329415.1)*

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your requirements and what other backups you have done since then, you could use (from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmreprt.htm#BRADV89594):

```
REPORT NEED BACKUP RECOVERY WINDOW OF n DAYS
Displays objects requiring backup to satisfy a recovery window-based retention policy.

REPORT NEED BACKUP REDUNDANCY n
Displays objects requiring backup to satisfy a redundancy-based retention policy.

REPORT NEED BACKUP DAYS n
Displays files that require more than n days' worth of archived redo log files for recovery.

REPORT NEED BACKUP INCREMENTAL n
Displays files that require application of more than n incremental backups for recovery.
```

These will tell you which files you need to backup to provide 'n' days worth of restore capability or 'n' redundancy.